# how to install program (.exe) using subprocess module in python

Tags: python-3.x

Need example for install program (.exe) using subprocess module in python 
I am using following code and got "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
I verified The path and it is correct

```
iv_arg = [ r'C:\Users\shlomil\Desktop\Utilities_Installers_new\Programs\iview444_x64_setup.exe']
subprocess.run(iv_arg)
```

Comment: try printing: `os.path.exists(iv_arg[0])` and report back

Comment: I got True for print(os.path.exists(iv_arg[0]))

Comment: are you running a 32 bit version of windows? can you try with another executable like notepad?

Comment: I'm using 64 bit version and when I trying  to do same operation on note pad I got different massage  OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: are you sure that is the line of the error? can you post the traceback? (those windows errors are sooo annoying, not telling you which file wasn't found, that's true)

Comment: I also would like to do silent install with out any pop-up during installation how do I combine that with subprocess module

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
iv_arg = "C:\\Users\\shlomil\\Desktop\\Utilities_Installers_new\\Programs\\iview444_x64_setup.exe"
subprocess.run(iv_arg, shell=True)
```